# Measuring correlation when multiple data points in a sample are provided by the same subject

Tags: correlation, rating

I want to measure the correlations between ratings on different items of a scale. In my sample, there are multiple data points from the same subjects, for each subject to the same extent. I am able to trace the ratings back to the subject who made them. What is the appropriate correlation measure accounting for these dependencies? I might need a non-parametric one.

Here's a toy example:
Subjects have to rate the acidity (item 1) and consistency (item 2) of fruit. Thus, they are shown different stimuli (apple, oranges, pears, ...) and rate for each fruit once on each item. Now I want to examine whether the two items acidity and consistency correlate somehow. Nevertheless, If I want to embrace all stimuli in my observation, there will be multiple ratings from the same subject. Nevertheless, there is only one rating per item, stimulus and subject.

Comment: I don't think this is enough information to allow good advice. The correlation is just the correlation; if repetition of observations among subjects is a real issue, you need to reduce the data to one per subject. No nonparametric measure will solve the dependency problem; that's the fallacy that distribution-free means assumption-free.

Comment: I think your issue is one of producing an appropriate model for the observations; the model should allow you to allocate the dependence in the data to the various sources of it in the model.

Comment: @Glen_b: Thanks. Can you please elaborate your comment further? An example might also be very helpful, and a concrete proposal even more. I am used to the model-term as something to fit to my data in order to explain them. Nevertheless, I do not understand the term in the context of correlations.

Comment: Multiple ratings from a subject yield a form of dependence between observations. The things you're looking for correlation between will be associated outside of that source of correlation. You will likely need a model that contains both forms of dependence in order to separate the two sources.

Comment: My take on your problem would be as follows: you have a number of variables, i.e. subject (a random effect), test type (fruit; a fixed effect), and a mysterious latent variable, which is responsible for the correlation between your two dependent variables. This is how I would attempt to model it -- using multivariate multiple regression and latent variable analysis. Unfortunately, I cannot give you any more hints.

Comment: Glen_b: Thank you very much. @January: What happened with the third variable "item within scale" in your model proposal? I want to find out whether there is a correlation between e.g. the items "acidity" and "consistency". This is the primary goal. Furthermore, the model should account for the fact that multiple data points come from the same subjects.

Comment: @Chris: your "item" is the latent variable that drives the correlation between two dependent variables (acidity and consistency). "fact that multiple data points come from the same subjects" means that here is a random effect of the subjects.